# How to upload a sound file from Android to a Rails webservice that's using paperclip gem?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, audio

I'm creating an app that haves a online webservice in RoR and an Android application. There's a model named Cry that have a paperclip attachement named "sound", how below:

```
class Cry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :dennies
  has_many :phones, :through => :votes
  validates :body, presence: true

  has_attached_file :sound
  validates_attachment_content_type :sound, :content_type => ["audio/mp3", "audio/3gp"]
end
```

and the controller is:

```
class CriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  # GET /cries
  # GET /cries.json
  def index
    @cries = Cry.all.page(params['page']).order('created_at DESC').per(10)
  end

  # GET /cries/1
  # GET /cries/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cries/new
  def new
    @cry = Cry.new
  end

  # GET /cries/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cries
  # POST /cries.json
  def create
    @cry = Cry.new(cry_params)

    #respond_to do |format|
      if @cry.save
        #format.html { redirect_to @cry, notice: 'Cry was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cry }
        render :json => @cry
      else
        #format.html { render :new }
        #format.json { render json: @cry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        render :json => { :errors => @cry.errors.full_messages }, :status => 422
      end
    #end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cries/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cries/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cry.update(cry_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cry, notice: 'Cry was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cry }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cries/1
  # DELETE /cries/1.json
  def destroy
    @cry.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cries_url, notice: 'Cry was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cry
      @cry = Cry.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cry_params
      params.require(:cry).permit(:body, :category, :sound)
    end
end
```

I sent sound files by the browser without problems, but I want send from my Android app. I'm tried do a multipart POST request, but because of the paperclip gem, it's not work.

How can I send to this webservice a audio file of a Android?

Log when I send from browser (it's ok!)

```
Started POST "/cries" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-03-01 02:53:13 +0000
Processing by CriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dmWpnPwlPmz+e4uxhM7l78Iv7E9Mh/Y8NT8vsEZxXsA8cfKACHETJUKnA5UDABFQUn1LrnzzvKh+Cl12ZVhqug==", "cry"=>{"body"=>":(", "sound"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd0d9debd70 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160301-5527-1yxq7k8.mp3>, @original_filename="189.mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cry[sound]\"; filename=\"189.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">, "category"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Cry"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/a2557a7b2e94197ff767970b6704169720160301-5527-1769qfr.mp3'
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/a2557a7b2e94197ff767970b6704169720160301-5527-1dmpum2.mp3'
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `cries` (`body`, `category`, `sound_file_name`, `sound_content_type`, `sound_file_size`, `sound_updated_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (':(', 1, '189.mp3', 'audio/mp3', 638256, '2016-03-01 02:53:13', '2016-03-01 02:53:13', '2016-03-01 02:53:13')
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 48ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Log when I send from Android (not work):

```
Started POST "/cries" for 10.0.2.2 at 2016-03-01 12:35:16 +0000
Processing by CriesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"cry"=>{"sound"=>"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018ftyp3gp4\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000isom3gp4\ --- a long sequence of unicode characteres ---", "body"=>"sound", "category"=>"1"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
  app/controllers/cries_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Comment: Is your log rails log showing any `POST` request coming in? I am assuming you are doing a post request on the end point `cries.json`. Try posting the logs here.

Comment: I'm send to http://192.168.0.102:3000/cries, not cries.json. Thanks

Comment: Looking your log it says `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`. I guess there seems some issue with char encoding in the post call. Please provide the code snippet where you are making this POST request in android.